# How to separate cells in Excel based on number pattern?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel organized as such:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Team        |        Points    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     (10) Alabama    |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Tulane       |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

That "(10)" is a ranking for a particular team at a given date. I want to separate the ranking from the team name so I have one column for rankings and the other for the team name, but I do not know how to put that together. I have tried using text to columns, but it created a bigger headache in removing the space between the ranking and team name and dealing with the parenthesis around the number.

Any solutions or ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
(10) Alabama
```

in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),"(",""),")","")
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999)
```

[image]

So we separate using the space character and then discard the ***(*** and the ***)***.